# OpenMP code slower than serial version

Tags: c++, openmp

I´m trying to parallelize a piece of code in c++ using openMP but I find slower result than serial version. 
I try to access element in a matrix I create, but I don´t see why this should affect the speed in the code I post below.

I´m starting learning openMP so probably I don´t see some evident mistakes.

This is the code:

```
long firstProcessorItem=numberColdStartItem/2;
long secondProcessorItem=numberColdStartItem-firstProcessorItem;
long processorId;
cout<<"ciao"<<endl;
#pragma omp parallel private(processorId) num_threads(2)
{
processorId=omp_get_thread_num();
cout<<processorId<<endl;
auto cpu=sched_getcpu();
cout<<"dsgahrtbw"<<cpu;
if (processorId==0) {
    cout<<"aaa"<<endl;
    for (int j=1; j<=firstProcessorItem; j++) {
        vector<CoupleItem<scalar>> vettoreCopie;
        vettoreCopie.resize(numberPastItem);

        auto& writeColumn=predictions.getColumnNonConst(j);
        vector<scalar>& readColumn=similarityPastFuture.getColumnNonConst(j);

        for (int i=numberUsers; i>=1; i--) {

            auto& readRow=userRatingPast.getRowNonConst(i);
            long int sizeReadRow=readRow.size();
            computeCoupleVector(readRow, readColumn, vettoreCopie);

            if (sizeReadRow>N) {
                std::sort(vettoreCopie.begin(),vettoreCopie.begin()+sizeReadRow,compare);
                writeColumn[i-1]=fastScalarProduct(vettoreCopie, N);
            } else {
                writeColumn[i-1]=fastScalarProduct(vettoreCopie, sizeReadRow);
            }
        }
    }
}
if (processorId==1) {
    cout<<"bbb"<<endl;
    for (int j=firstProcessorItem+1; j<=numberColdStartItem; j++) {
        vector<CoupleItem<scalar>> vettoreCopie;
        vettoreCopie.resize(numberPastItem);

        auto& writeColumn=predictions.getColumnNonConst(j);
        vector<scalar>& readColumn=similarityPastFuture.getColumnNonConst(j);

        for (int i=1; i<=numberUsers; i++) {

            auto& readRow=userRatingPast.getRowNonConst(i);
            long int sizeReadRow=readRow.size();
            computeCoupleVector(readRow, readColumn, vettoreCopie);

            if (sizeReadRow>N) {
                std::sort(vettoreCopie.begin(),vettoreCopie.begin()+sizeReadRow,compare);
                writeColumn[i-1]=fastScalarProduct(vettoreCopie, N);
            } else {
                writeColumn[i-1]=fastScalarProduct(vettoreCopie, sizeReadRow);
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Does someone has any idea of this behaviour?
Thank you very much!

Comment: How large is your data? If it is not being enough, spawning multiple threads may be heavier than your actual work. Try to increase its size (a lot! Depending on how much slower is your parallel code). Also, there are some room for improvements at the way you split work between threads, but this will not improve speed.

Comment: It's quite big... It takes 60 second to run the serial version and around 70 to run the parallel.

Comment: I have no idea what is wrong. To be sure, you have at last a dual core processor, right? If this is exactly dual core, is it AMD or Intel? AMD don't have SMT implemented, only CMT, which is slower than SMT in most tasks.

Comment: How many cores does your processor have?  If it only has one core, then the parallel version would be slower than the serial version.